# Firebase authentication pre-built UI for React Native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm currently building an app with react native and firebase. I was looking to add firebase authentication and was wondering if there is a way to add firebases pre-built authentication UI to a react native app? I looked through the authentication information for Web in firebases docs but the configuration requires a redirectURL to send the user to once they're signed in which I don't have for a react native app. If it helps, I am using a Stack Navigator in my react app. Is there a work around or will I just have to create a custom UI?